# UIView added to SKScene have strange border

Tags: uiview, sprite-kit

I need to add UIView with white background (have HUD class that is used through out the app)  to the SKScene with white background. The code is something like this:

```
class CategoriesGameScene: SKScene  {
      override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

      let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenWidth, height: 50))
      view.backroundColor = UIColor.white

}
      }
```

Everything works, however there is a problem - on the border of the UIView there is small black/greyish border (so two views are not "blending") with each other. The funny thing is when I am trying to make a screenshot (so I can post an example here) - there is no border on the screenshot and everything looks as it should and also if i am tapping homebutton to multitasking view on the iphone line is also disappearing. Is there a proper way to add UIView to SKScene or can I try something different to get rid of that?

Comment: This is also happens only on the device, not in simulator

Comment: Just to keep this in mind...You can't add `UIView` to the scene. You can add it to a view controller's view property. Scene is a node (presented by the `SKView`). And it can contain only nodes. Still, I don't really get what is the issue here. Maybe you can upload an example project on Github, so I can look at it.

Comment: Could be any number of problems with how things are blending, from Metal to retina display problems.  May also be the device you are using, where scaling is causing artifacts.  BTW @Whirlwind long time no see.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Sup? Yeah, didn't have enough time for SO, but I am always around.

Comment: @Whirlwind yes right, I think the Knight0fDragon bet is right because it is clearly looks like a kind of a glitch and the fact that it is not showing on the screenshots is proving that.

Comment: @Whirlwindregarding the code here as an example full code from new spritekit project: import SpriteKit
class GameScene: SKScene {

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        
      scene?.backgroundColor = SKColor.white
      let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 50, height: 50))
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        self.view?.addSubview(view)
        
    }
   
}

Comment: Hmm, actually just tried it on the iphone x and there is no such problem, but still on the iphone 8 plus

Comment: @AlexeyDemidov Why do you need `UIView` at all ? Tend to use sprites (SKSpriteNode) in SpriteKit. Of course, this is not a must, but I could think of plenty of reasons and situation, about why SKSpriteNode makes more sense in SpriteKit app(send me an email if you like, and I will explain you there, because I don't want to go off-topic). Also, does something changes if you use `SKSpriteNode` rather than `UIView`?

Comment: @Whirlwind well I am using same HUD class through other parts of the app (which are purely UIKit) and I have one part of the app with a game scene (small game inside an app) so I thought it is a good idea to use same code and not to write all functionality again in spritekit. Was thought that I was doing something wrong but seems like you mention render bug or something because this happens in my case only on the iPhone 8 plus (real device) and not on iphone x or simulator.

Comment: iphone 8+ has built in hardware scaling you need to factor in.  That is most likely causing your problem. (When you make a screen shot it gives you the unscaled version, which is why you are not seeing the border)

Comment: It is way to much to explain in an answer unfortunately, but you need to change settings in your storyboard and apply better constraints so that your HUD properly overlays over your SKView

Comment: I will try to play around with it, but still not sure how it applies to my example code (please see comment above) that is the whole code that represent this behaviour, no constraints or something just this.

Comment: You do not have any constraints, and that is the problem.  You have a view that is slapped onto another view, then it is being scaled. The final value of your top view after scaling is a fraction of a pixel smaller than the final value of the bottom view after scaling.  This can happen because of how floats work, especially when converting float to pixel coordinates, which can't be decimal (think about what 1/2 a pixel means [ignoring sub pixels].)  Your decimal has to be rounded, so because all of the math involved, on the top view it is rounding down, and on your bottom it is rounding up.

Comment: Now note, depending on what else is going on,  you may have auto constraints being added that you do not know about, and that too may not be achieving what you want.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon oh, okay, i understand now, will try to dig in to it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this issue by checking "Allow Transparency" option of SKView properties in Storyboard.